# How to make other subdirectory work with cakephp in root?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have this path in my hosting server with domain `http://www.example.com/` and it's running cakephp in the directory `home`. but now I want my `another_project_name` appear in browser with `http://www.example.com/another_project_name/`.

This is my structure :

```
/www
    .htaccess
    home/
        .htaccess
        webroot/
            .htaccess
    lib/
    another_project_name/
```

This is my `/www/.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ home/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) home/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How to configure `.htaccess` file in `/www/.htaccess` to make my `another_project_name` work ?

Comment: You should only have one htaccess - the one in webroot. the document root should be pointed there, not on the parent folder.

Comment: +1 :D but I want it in the document root `/www/another_project_name/` so that I can find any other projects there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (another_project_name/.*) $1 [L] # adjust the regex to what you want.
RewriteRule (another_project_name.*) $1 [L] # adjust the regex to what you want.

RewriteRule    ^$ home/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) home/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess file should be like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(another_project_name)/(.*)$ 
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

For multiple directories

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(another_project_name1 | another_project_name2 | another_project_name3 )/(.*)$
```